# Connecting to IIS website from another computer on the LAN - port not listening

Tags: iis, networking

I have website working fine on my local machine as host name hml.frontend in the hosts file: 127.0.0.1  hml.frontend

In IIS I have bindings as hml.frontend 127.0.0.1 and hml.frontend 192.168.1.94. The latter I used ipconfig to get my local ip address issued to me by my BT Home Hub 5 router.

In windows 10 firewall I have allowed App/Feature NetLogon service and World Wide Web services (HTTP).

In advanced settings in Inbound Rules I have added a rule which allow the connection from all sources to ports 80 and 443. Scope is any IP addresses.

On my macbook I have added the 192.168.1.94 as hml.frontend to the hosts file.

I can ping hml.frontend OK from the macbook.

However from a web browser the http://hml.frontend site cannot be reached from the macbook.

telnet 192.168.1.94 80 from the macbook says unable to connect to remote host.

Back on the PC I have done netstat -na to see which ports IIS is listening on and 127.0.0.1:80 is there and so is 192.168.1.94:139 and many more ports against that IP address but not port 80.

Any ideas what I can check to get my PC to listen for that website hostname on port 80?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work, I was on the right track that the IP address was not being listened to.

In order to add the ip address I have to be listened to, I went into cmd as adminstrator, did

```
netsh
http
show iplisten
```

'show' result shows that just 127.0.0.1 was being listened on port 80

```
add iplisten ipaddress=192.168.1.94
show iplisten
quit
```

'show' result shows that now additionally 192.168.1.94 is being listened on port 80

Then I went back in with

```
netstat -na
```

And now I see the line I want:

TCP   192.168.1.94:80  0.0.0.0:0 LISTENING

Some information was gained from this article.

http://windowsitpro.com/windows-server/solve-iis-listener-problems

The site is now reachable from my macbook using the hostname http://hml.frontend

Comment: Thank you, super helpful, exactly what I needed ... was driving me crazy when IIS was set to listen on all IP Addresses, but wasn't....

Comment: windowsitpro.com link is no longer valid.